# Undefined method downcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make my search method work for Heoku. I had the problem before and adding .downcase to it fixed it. 
But now, it doesn't work and I get 
undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

listing.rb

```
def self.locsearch(search_location, search_description)
  return scroped unless search_location.present? && search_description.present?
  where(["LOWER(location) LIKE? AND LOWER(description) LIKE?", "%#{search_location.downcase}%", "%#{search_description.downcase}%"])
end
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

I changed it to

```
def self.locsearch(location, description)
  if location.present? && description.present?
  where(["LOWER(location) LIKE? AND LOWER(description) LIKE?", "%#{location.downcase}%", "%#{description.downcase}%"])
else
  self.all
end
end
```

Now it returns all listings, even if my input of location and description matches a certain listing.
Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning scroped only if both search_location and search_description are present.

If only one of them is nil, the next line is executed and downcase is called on nil.

I would rewrite your code something like this:

```
self.search_location(location, description)
    if location.present? && description.present?
        where(["LOWER(location) LIKE? AND LOWER(description) LIKE?",
          "%#{location.downcase}%", "%#{description.downcase}%"])
    else
        scroped #not sure what it is, maybe you need another name for this?
    end
end
```

This way it is easier to spot mistakes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this works. I replaced scroped (which was meant to be scoped but I used it wrong) with self.all.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `search_location` or else `search_description` is `nil`, so when you try to call its `downcase` method, there is none.  Hence the error.

By the way, you probably mean `scoped` rather than `scroped`.